# Error in partial derivative and replace?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

After run my code, output is

```
(2^(-2 \[Alpha]) Sqrt[\[Pi]] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(0\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y])/(\[Alpha] Gamma[\[Alpha]] Gamma[
  1/2 + \[Alpha]])
```

I want to replace the following output in it:

```
Subscript[a, 0][x, y] -> -(1/4) E^((Sqrt[r] (x + y))/(2 Sqrt[2]))
```

But I have error

[image: error]
. Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: As a rule of thumb avoid `Subscripts` in *Mathematica* unless you are typesetting something

Comment: @Sektor How use of Subscript[a, 0][x, y] in Mathematica?

Comment: Or what is correct form?

Comment: With respect to the comment by @Sektor, just use `a0`, for instance.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey what is good introduce for the following series:    "\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 0\), \(m\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(n\)]\)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FullForm` or, more conveniently here, `InputForm` to see what the original expression looks like internally:

```
(Sqrt[Pi]*Derivative[2, 0][Subscript[a, 0]][x, y])/(2^(2*α)*α*Gamma[α]*Gamma[1/2 + α])
```

`Subscript[a, 0][x, y]` does not actually appear here.  Instead, `Derivative[2, 0][Subscript[a, 0]][x, y]` does.  Consequently, the whole derivative must be replaced.  Use

```
Derivative[2, 0][Subscript[a, 0]][x, y] -> 
    D[-(1/4) E^((Sqrt[r] (x + y))/(2 Sqrt[2])), {x, 2}]
```

which yields

```
(* -((2^(-5 - 2 α) E^((Sqrt[r] (x + y))/(2 Sqrt[2]))Sqrt[π] r)/
    (α Gamma[α] Gamma[1/2 + α])) *)
```

This particular Mathematica behavior is not at all user-friendly.

Comment: I use FullForm[(2^(-2 \[Alpha]) Sqrt[\[Pi]] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(0\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y])/(\[Alpha] Gamma[\[Alpha]] Gamma[
   1/2 + \[Alpha]])]       and I have error.

Comment: @Bahram  What error do you have?  Did you copy the `Rule` in my answer and apply it to your original expression?

Comment: If possible for you  which put complete code with 'FullForm'.

Comment: @Bahram  Just type `//FullForm` or, better yet, `//InputForm` after the code at the top of your question and run it.

Comment: I have problem with  "//InputForm " and ''//FullForm".

Comment: @ bbgodfrey I added picture of error.

Comment: @bahram  You are running in `Debugger` mode.  Turn it off and try again.

Comment: @bahram  Open *Evaluation* on the menu bar.  You should see *Debugger* with a check mark next to it.  Click *Debugger* to clear the check mark.  By the way, *Debugger* is not on by default, so it seems likely that someone turned it on at some point.

Comment: Many many thanks.